# regex strip off words from line - proceeded by java

Tags: java, regex

Im trying to strip off one word from line my backend is java

I did the following. Example line:

```
TICKET0041960 Fix code at css
```

I want to strip off `TICKET0041960` so the result will be

```
Fix code at css
```

I used this

```
TICKET[.0-9]
```

and I ended up with  result as

```
 041960 Fix code at css
```

Any tips to adjust regex to strip off TICKET0041960   consider numbers always random

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TICKET[.0-9]` means *the string TICKET followed by either a dot or a digit between 0 and 9*.

What you actually need is `TICKET[0-9]+`: *the string TICKET followed by one or more digits between 0 and 9*.

`[0-9]` can be simplified to `\d` (i.e. `TICKET\d+`), but don't forget to escape the backslash in Java since in a string literal (i.e. `TICKET\\d+`).

You may want to remove the leading space(s) as well: `TICKET\d+\s+` (again, `TICKET\\d+\\s+` for Java).

Comment: works fine , i went down with 2nd option  TICKET\\d+